# Angular 4: Passing object to Routes without updating Query Params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using Angular 4 and I want to pass some object to router but without updating query params.

**user.component.ts**

```
this.router.navigate(["/profile",{
   action: 'edit',
   user: {id: 1, name: 'test', email: 'test@mail.com'}
}]);
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: 'profile', component: UserProfileComponent }
```

**user-profile.component.ts**

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

});
```

Any help?

Comment: Use a shared service.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of how to share data using a service: http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Comment: Would Redux be a better approach in this case? I'm always in doubt which one should I use on scenarios like this... Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The Redux pattern is a commitment and if you opt to use it, it is best used for all of your application state. If you just need a simple solution, a service is a good way to go. If you want to buy into the Redux pattern, then NgRx is a great way to handle this.

Comment: Hi @DeborahK what do you prefer now still use a service to share the data or by using state property ? or is there a new way ?

Comment: Yes, I use a service to share all of the data in my application. Within the service I may use a state property, or if I'm managing streams, an Observable operator such as `shareReplay`.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of angular 7.3 and above router `navigate` and `navigateByUrl`  methods accept another parameter with type `NavigationExtras` has a property called state accept an object , after we set the state value we can get the value in the target component by access to history object so just like this we have pass an object betwwen routes.

set the state

```
 const user = {id: 1 , name : '...' , address : {country: '...' , city : '...'}}
 this._router.navigate([`details`,user.id] , {state:{...user} });
```

in the details component we can access the state value like this

```
 this.user = window.history.state;
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-share-object)

Comment: On Refresh will loose the data

Comment: also if you use a shared service this the same @user630209